# Loading DL4J trained Word2Vec Model into gensim

Tags: python, gensim, word2vec, dl4j

Hello I have some word2vec models generated using Word2Vec java implementation in [DL4J](https://deeplearning4j.org/docs/latest/deeplearning4j-nlp-word2vec) and saved by calling

```
writeWord2VecModel(Word2Vec vectors, String path)
```

The output of that is a zip file that contains a bunch of txt files.
I can successfully load and use the model in DL4j using

```
Word2Vec readWord2VecModel(String path)
```

I am now trying to read that model in python, using `gensim`

```
import gensim

model = gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('file_path, binary=False)
```

But I get the following error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe0 in position 10: invalid continuation byte
```

I also tried with binary=True and get same results.

If I extract the model generated by DL4J I get the following files:

[image: List Of Files]

Is there a way to read that model in python `genism`?

Answer (score 1):

None of the filenames shown in your image are of types `gensim` can read as word-vectors.

What file path and filename are you supplying to `load_word2vec_format()`? (None of `gensim`'s load-methods can take a `.zip` archive.)

There might be another way to export the vectors from DL4J, into word2vec.c-format (text or binary, single file), rather than a full model ZIP archive.

If you succeed in that, try supplying such a single file to `load_word2vec_format()`, with the appropriate `binary` value.

(If at that point you have a right-formatted file, but you're still getting Unicode errors – perhaps later in the file – there's an optional `unicode_errors='ignore'` argument that can be provided to [`load_word2vec_format()`](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/keyedvectors.html#gensim.models.keyedvectors.Word2VecKeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format) for charging-through Unicode errors – but I don't think that's your main problem, nor would it be your problem if DL4J could export word-vectors the right way.)